# How can I move to the next page after clicking onto the submit button, I can't move even after clicking on the submit button

Tags: html

How can i move to the next page after clicking onthe submit button, in my case my submit button is not working. I used some JQuery code inside this html page, is that a reason?

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="form_table_output.html" name="myform" method="post" style="width: 1200px; margin:0px auto">
  <h1 title="Cycle calculation"> Cycle Time Calculation INSIGNUM </h1>
  <hr><br>

  <table border="0" cellpadding="18" cellspacing="10" style="margin:0px 40px;">
    <tr>  
                <td style="width: 50%">
                    <label for="to_check_recognition"><b>Do you have to check Orientation? <span style="color:red">*</span></b></label><br><br>
                    <select id="to_check_recognition" name="to_check_recognition" style="width: 350px; height: 35px; border-radius: 8px" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected > Please Select... </option>
                        <option value="yes"> Yes</option>
                        <option value="no"> No </option> 
                    </select><br><br>
                </td> 
                <td style="width: 50%">
                    <div  id = "Average_orientation" style="display: none;">
                    <label for="Average_orientation"><b>Average amount of orientation check per panel <span style="color:red">*</span></b></label><br><br>
                    <input type = "number" step="any" name = "Average_orientation" style="width: 350px; height: 25px; border-radius: 8px" required /><br><br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    Orientation();
                    $("#to_check_recognition").change(function() {
                        Orientation();
                    });
                });
                function Orientation() {
                    if ($("#to_check_recognition").val() == 'yes')
                        $("#Average_orientation").show();
                    else
                        $("#Average_orientation").hide();
                }
            </script>
            <tr> 
             <td colspan="2" style="text-align: right; height: 225px">
                    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Click To Submit" style="width: 200px; height: 50px; border-radius: 12px; color: blue; background: gold; cursor: pointer;" />
                </td> 
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
  </html>
```

Comment: If you use JQuery code please can you show the code? Edit your question and update. THanks

Comment: @Martin I just edit my code, this web page is very long i just added only small portion of my webpage

Comment: thanks. the code you show should not stop the form submitting. Can you look at your page in a browser Inspector? What does that tell you?

Comment: An invalid form control with name='codesize2' is not focusable. i get this error. Actually i am using conditional statements int he entire page and not all the input fields are filled when the user select No in this case it is created problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given `required` attribute to input:

```
<input type = "number" step="any" name = "Average_orientation" style="width: 350px; height: 25px; border-radius: 8px" required />
```

When you select `no` & input is hidden, due to required attribute, form is not submitted.

Change value of input to `0` then submit form:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="form_table_output.html" name="myform" method="post" style="width: 1200px; margin:0px auto">
  <h1 title="Cycle calculation"> Cycle Time Calculation INSIGNUM </h1>
  <hr><br>

  <table border="0" cellpadding="18" cellspacing="10" style="margin:0px 40px;">
    <tr>  
                <td style="width: 50%">
                    <label for="to_check_recognition"><b>Do you have to check Orientation? <span style="color:red">*</span></b></label><br><br>
                    <select id="to_check_recognition" name="to_check_recognition" style="width: 350px; height: 35px; border-radius: 8px" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected > Please Select... </option>
                        <option value="yes"> Yes</option>
                        <option value="no"> No </option> 
                    </select><br><br>
                </td> 
                <td style="width: 50%">
                    <div  id = "Average_orientation" style="display: none;">
                    <label for="Average_orientation"><b>Average amount of orientation check per panel <span style="color:red">*</span></b></label><br><br>
                    <input type = "number" step="any" name = "Average_orientation" style="width: 350px; height: 25px; border-radius: 8px" required /><br><br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    Orientation();
                    $("#to_check_recognition").change(function() {
                        Orientation();
                    });
                });
                function Orientation() {
                    if($("#to_check_recognition").val() == 'yes'){
                        $("#Average_orientation").show();$("input[name=Average_orientation]").val("");}else if($("#to_check_recognition").val() == 'no'){
                  $("#Average_orientation"). hide();$("input[name=Average_orientation]").val("0");  }
                }
            </script>
            <tr> 
             <td colspan="2" style="text-align: right; height: 225px">
                    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Click To Submit" style="width: 200px; height: 50px; border-radius: 12px; color: blue; background: gold; cursor: pointer;" />
                </td> 
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Actually, this is mandatory field that user must have to fill if the user select yes, and it is not possible to remove required attribute from the  input fields, how can i fix this problem without removing the required attribute?

Comment: Ok. You can change value to 0 then submit

Comment: Where do I have to put value to 0?

Answer (score 0):

> in my case my submit button is not working

When I am testing your code I am correctly redirecting to "form_table_output.html"

What do you mean, when you click nothing happen or when you click something happen but it is not what you want?

Comment: if i choose no and then press submit button then I am not redirecting to the next page but, if i choose yes and fill the next input field that appear after and then press submit button then it redirect to the next page, how can i fix such problem

Comment: Use comments to ask for more information or suggest some improvements. Please avoid posting answers to ask a question. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

submit button is working fine and correctly redirect to "form_table_output.html".
But the error is a bad path i.e. this is path "form_table_output.html" not exist. So please define it in your codebase.

Comment: f I select no and then press submit button then I am not redirecting to the next page but, if I select yes and fill the next input field that appear after and then press submit button then it redirect to the next page, how can i fix such problem?

Comment: @waqas When you selecting "no" and press submits button not redirecting because you have made the "required" field. You have to remove "required" from the input field you want to redirect on "no" select dynamically.